# Excel looping, formulas, and merging rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel data dump that I am trying to parse out into a report. I think that I need to use loops but my VBA is not up to snuff, haven't used it since college. I've been searching online, but my problem is I don't even know what to search to get specifically what I need. Any advice is appreciated, even if it's just pointing me in the right direction.  If I figure this out based on advice, I will post the solution later.

My data dump looks something like this (with many more fields/columns):
[image: Excel Screenshot with ID, Title, Rev, State, Date Changed columns]
My issue is with having multiple rows per ID and with the Date Changed field essentially being using for multiple purposes, as I need to pull the time between Approved to Done.

Here's what I have gotten so far:
[image: Excel Screenshot with Added Approved Date and Done Date columns]

I have made the data into a table, and created new columns for Approved Date and Done date.  I put in a formula that says if the State = Approved, grab the Date Changed, and the same for Done Date.  Otherwise I put N/A.

So now I need to go through each ID (I am thinking needs to use looping but not sure what type), keep just the rows with Approved or Done and drop the others.  Then I need to merge the rows so that there's just one row per ID, so I have the approved and done dates on the same row, and then get the date diff.  But the issue with all this is that some of these haven't been approved or done yet (will just drop those I think), some never hit the Approval state but did hit the Done state (have them throw an error about not using correct process?), and some have been changed multiple times so you actually have Approved or Done coming up multiple times per ID.  So then I need to only keep the first one and drop the others?

And THEN I need to write it into a macro so it's repeatable and as idiot proof as possible.  :(

So my thought is that I need to loop through each ID, and end that loop when it hits the next ID.  Inside that loop I need to set variables for the Approved and Done states and then create the Time to Complete and each loop needs to then write to a new sheet, with one ID per row and the relevant information, throwing the "Did not complete process" error when it was skipped and dumping the IDs that just have not finished the process yet (difference between missing Approved and missing Done).

Am I totally overthinking this?  I am hoping to get something that I can then hand off to non-technical people where they can take their data dump and I won't have to do this for them every week, hence wanting to make it into a macro.

Thank you for any help or advice!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  It is a place to get specific help with existing code that does not work.  If you have problematic code please post it in the original post, with a specific explanation of what is wrong.  As is this question is too broad for this forum.

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to get someone to code for me, I am trying to get pointers to the right direction to look. I think I need to use nested loops but I'm not even sure what to search. :(  Kind of stuck until I can even search for something, but everything I've tried is too broad and what I've found is just "yes, nested loops are a thing you can do" unfortunately. I had hoped I could get pointed in the right direction here. If I figure it out ever I'll post the answer.